# Laurent series of $1/((z+i)*(z+1))$ about $z=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out this Laurent Series.
The question is, find the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{(z+i)(z+1)}$ about the point $z=0$.

I have attempted to solve this by first finding the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z+i}$ and the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z+1}$ and then applying the termwise multiplication rule to find the series above.
I have worked out the series for $\frac{1}{z+1}$ to be

$$\frac{1}{z+1}\\
\frac{1}{1+z}\\
\frac{1}{1-(-z)}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-z)^n\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^n
$$

I verified this using wolfram alpha, I know that $\frac{1}{\frac{i}{2} + 1} \approx .8-.4i$. Plugging the above formula into wolfram alpha ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n=0%20to%20100%20of%20%28-1%29%5En%2a%28i/2%29%5En)) I got the same result.

I then worked out the series for $\frac{1}{z+i}$ to be
$$
\frac{1}{z+i}\\
\frac{1}{i+z}\\
\frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{i}}\\
\frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{1}{1-iz}\\
\frac{1}{i} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (iz)^n\\
-i \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} i^n z^n\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^1 i^{n+1} z^n
$$

Again using wolfram alpha with the point $\frac{1}{\frac{i}{2}+i} \approx -.66i$ ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n=0%20to%20100%20of%20-%28i%5E%28n%2b1%29%29%2a%28i/2%29%5En)) I get the same result.

So I multiply both of these series termwise by each other to obtain this series

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n z^n \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^1 i^{n+1} z^n
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \cdot i^{n+1} \cdot z^{2n}
$$

However, I *should* get $\frac{1}{(\frac{i}{2}+1)(\frac{i}{2}+i)} \approx -.26-.53i$ but wolfram alpha gives me $.23-.94i$ instead. ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n=0%20to%20100%20of%20%28-1%29%5E%28n%2b1%29%2a%28i%5E%28n%2b1%29%29%2a%28i/2%29%5E%282n%29))

So, my question is *where* have I gone wrong? Is there a reason why I cannot termwise multiply these two series? As far as I can tell they are both series about $z=0$ so I am not sure why what I'm doing won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't multiply power series termwise, the product is the Cauchy product, $(a_0 + a_1z + a_2 z^2 + \dotsc)(b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2+\dotsc) = a_0b_0 + (a_0b_1+a_1b_0)z + (a_0b_2 + a_1b_1+a_2b_0)z^2 + \dotsc$

Comment: You term-wise multiplication is faulty:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\right)^2 = \frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4} \neq \sum_{i=1}^n i^2$$
But as the function is non-singular in $z=0$ you only have to compute the Taylor series for said function at $z=0$.

Comment: So, to clarify, does termwise multiplication only work for some scalar multiplied by a series?

How would I go about finding out this series then? Should I split them up into partial fractions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you multiply two power series to get a new power series,

$$\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n \right)
  \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n z^n \right)
= \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n \right)$$

The new series isn't a sum of term-wise product like what you have imagined.
The coefficients $c_n$ of the new series is given by:

$$c_n = a_0 b_n + a_1 b_{n-1} + \cdots + a_n b_0$$

This sort of product is called [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), you can find more info on its wiki.

For the problem at hand, you should obtain the expansion by first decomposing your original expression into partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{(z+i)(z+1)} = \frac{1}{1-i}\left(\frac{1}{z+i}-\frac{1}{z+1}\right)
= \frac{1+i}{2}\left(\frac{-i}{1-iz}-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)\\
=\frac{1+i}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(i^{n-1}-(-1)^n\right)z^n
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(-i z^{4n} + (i+1) z^{4n+2} - z^{4n+2}\right)$$